# position: sticky; não funciona

Tags: css

Estou tentando fazer com que o `thead` da tabela fique com `position: sticky`, para assim sempre ficar no topo do scroll, porém não está funcionando e não acho uma solução.

OBS: estou usando Bootstrap e a classe `sticky-top` também não funcionou.

```css
    html, body {
      height: 100em;
    }

    thead{
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        top: 0; 
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
```

```html
<table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td >CLIENTE</td>
            <td>SEGMENTO</td>
            <td>STATUS</td>
            <td>ATIVAÇÂO</td>
            <td>EC</td>
            <td>ESTADO</td>
            <td>CIDADE</td>
            
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td>client</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td> client</td>
            <td>client</td>
          </tr>
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É pq o `position:sticky` não funciona no `thead`, e sim no `th`

Segue um exemplo

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 250px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Mesmo assim parece não ter um suporte bom nos browser

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Answer (score 1):

O sticky não vai funcionar no elemento `thead` (nem no `tr`) no **Chrome**. Você terá que usar em todos os `td`'s que estão no `thead`:

```css
html, body {
   height: 100em;
}

thead td{
   position: sticky;
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   top: 0; 
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td >CLIENTE</td>
      <td>SEGMENTO</td>
      <td>STATUS</td>
      <td>ATIVAÇÂO</td>
      <td>EC</td>
      <td>ESTADO</td>
      <td>CIDADE</td>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td>client</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td> client</td>
      <td>client</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Funcionar, funciona... É só usar Firefox.. hahahaha

Comment: rs.. esqueci de mencionar o Chrome.

Comment: O pior é que só funciona em Firefox e Safari...
Nem dá pra dizer que isso é compatibilidade. hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a única forma de conseguir isso, é quebrando a tabela em 2 partes.
Veja o exemplo abaixo

```css
body{
  color:#fff; 
  font-family:arial; 
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size:40px; 
}
.main-container{ 
  max-width:600px; 
  margin:0 auto; 
  border:solid 10px green; 
  padding:10px; 
  margin-top:40px;
}
.main-container *{
  padding:10px;
  background:#aaa; 
}
.main-container * + *{
  margin-top:5px;
}

.main-content{
  min-height:1000px;
}

.main-header{
  position:-webkit-sticky; 
  position:sticky; 
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-container">
  <header class="main-header">
    <table>
      <thead>
<tr>
        <td >CLIENTE</td>
        <td>SEGMENTO</td>
        <td>STATUS</td>
        <td>ATIVAÇÂO</td>
        <td>EC</td>
        <td>ESTADO</td>
        <td>CIDADE</td>
        
      </tr>
</thead>
    </table>
  </header>  
  <div class="main-content">
    <table>
      <tbody>
<tr>
        <td>client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td>client</td>
      </tr>
<tr>
        <td>client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td>client</td>
      </tr>
<tr>
        <td>client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td> client</td>
        <td>client</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>
```